# Unset associative array by value

Tags: php

I'd like to remove an array item by value. Key cannot be specified. Here is the array. I have sorted the array by value, numeric descending.

```
Array
(
    [this] => 15
    [that] => 10
    [other] => 9
    [random] => 8
    [keys] => 4
)
```

If I want to unset all items that have a value less than 10. How do I do that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: That's only a one-dimenional array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$test = array(
    "this" => 15,
    "that" => 10,
    "other" => 9,
    "random" => 8,
    "keys" => 4
);

echo "pre: ";print_r($test);
pre: Array ( [this] => 15 [that] => 10 [other] => 9 [random] => 8 [keys] => 4 )
```

Run this code:

```
foreach($test AS $key => $value) {
    if($value <= 10) {
        unset($test[$key]);
    }
}
```

Results are:

```
echo "post: ";print_r($test);
post: Array ( [this] => 15 )
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) function:

```
$a = array_filter($a, function($x) { return !($x < 10); });
```

Comment: I knew there was a better, more elegant way of doing this... This the answer. For older versions `$a = array_filter($a,'functionName');` you must pass a string to with the name of a previously declared function

Comment: Good answer. Not using 5.3+ though.

Comment: Well, for pre-5.3 it's just a matter of replacing the inline function with a valid callback, which may be either a string or a `create_function` call.

Comment: Should be `$x < 10`?

Comment: @robsch: haha, YES! thanks for spotting the mistake 4 years later :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
  if( $value < 10 )
    unset($array[$key])
```

Comment: How is a reference to a value going to make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all values are ints:

```
for (i=9;i>=0;i--)
{
    while (array_search($i, $assocArray) !== false)
    {
        unset($assocArray[array_search($i, $assocArray)]);
    }
}
```

There probably are more elegant ways of doing this, but fever has a firm grip on my brain :)

knittl's answer is correct, but if you're using an older version of PHP, you can' t use the anonymous function, just do:

```
function filterFunc($v)
{
    return $v >= 10;
}
$yourArray = array_filter($yourArray,'filterFunc');
```

Credit to Knittl